# About generics in java

Tags: java, generics

I have a question about generics, I know what `<E>` means, but what does `<E> void` mean?

```
public static <E> void append(List<E> list) {

}
```

I thought about `<E>` void but I don't know what it means.

Comment: `<E> void` is two separate things, `<E>` and `void`.  The latter is the method return type, as normal. The former is part of the syntax for a generic method, declaring the method's type parameter.  This is different from a method of a generic class that uses the class's type parameter(s) -- here, the type parameter belongs to the method itself, and is resolved separately for each invocation.

Answer (score 2):

`void` is the return type for the `append` method, that's independent of the generic type `E`.

Answer (score 1):

In that method declaration, `void` is the return type. `<E>` is the declaration of the method's type parameter, which is necessary when the class itself does not have a matching type parameter because the method argument uses `<E>` as a type parameter.

In this case, `<E>` and `void` have nothing to do with each other.